# pygame.key.get_pressed() is not working

Tags: python, pygame

I've read similar questions to this on Stack Overflow but they have not helped. Here is my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(1)

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
    clock.tick(60)

    keyState = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keyState[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        print('\nGame Shuting Down!')
        done = True
```

Pressing `escape` does not exit the game or print a message. Is this a bug? If I print the value for keyState[pygame.K_ESCAPE], it is always zero.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that you don't process pygame's event queue. You should simple call `pygame.event.pump()` at the end of your loop and then your code works fine:

```
...
while not done:
    clock.tick(60)

    keyState = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keyState[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        print('\nGame Shuting Down!')
        done = True
    pygame.event.pump() # process event queue
```

From the [docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) (emphasis mine):

> **pygame.event.pump()**
>
> *internally process pygame event handlers*
>
> `pump() -> None`
>
> ***For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.*** If you are not using other event functions in your game, you should call pygame.event.pump() to allow pygame to handle internal actions.
>
> This function is not necessary if your program is consistently processing events on the queue through the other pygame.event functions.
>
> There are important things that must be dealt with internally in the event queue. The main window may need to be repainted or respond to the system. ***If you fail to make a call to the event queue for too long, the system may decide your program has locked up***.

Note that you don't have to do this if you just call `pygame.event.get()` anywhere in your main-loop; if you do not, you should probably call `pygame.event.clear()` so the event queue will not fill up.

Comment: Actually you might only need to call `pygame.event.poll()` which might be slightly faster.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest using an event que instead? It's probably a better idea:

```
while True: #game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get(): #loop through all the current events, such as key presses. 
        if event.type == QUIT:
            die()

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE: #it's better to have these as multiple statments in case you want to track more than one type of key press in the future. 
                pauseGame()
```

Comment: I was using this method before but it doesn't handle simultaneous key presses very well.

Comment: You can set Boolean values to variables and make them be True when there is a `keydown` and them make them false again when there there is a `keyup`. Then you just check which of the variables are true. I'll edit my answer with an example in a second

Comment: @ZeroDivide you can mix and match, using events and get_state depending on what keys should use which.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(1)

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key[K_ESCAPE]:
        print('\nGame Shuting Down!')

    pygame.display.flip()
```

you dont need the `pygame.`on the if statment and also you should call `pygame.display.flip()` so it properly shows the window then you need an event loop to exit the program

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the version of `pygame` and `python`.

I met the similar issue when I use `pygame 1.9.4dev` and `python 3.6.5`

I fix this problem after I downgrade `pygame` and reinstall `python`.

**NOTE**: If you use `pyenv`, you must make sure `--enable-framework` option is set when installing python.

```
# exit current virtualenv
$ pyenv deactivate
# reinstall python
$ PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-framework" pyenv install 3.6.5
# And reinstall pygame again.
pip install https://github.com/pygame/pygame/archive/1.9.3.zip
```

Use the following code to check whether it is work.

```
import pygame
import sys


def run():
    """Initialize pygame, settings, and screen object."""
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 200))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Keyboard Test')

    # main loop
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                print('KEY pressed is ' + str(event.key) + '.')

        # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
        pygame.display.flip()


run()
```