# Pygame: Move picture while key is being held

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, pygame

i´m trying to move picture while key is being held, but it always moves just by one pixel. In questions similar to this I saw this is right, but it is not working for me.

```
import pygame, sys

x = 0
y = 0


class Ship:
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)

    def Play(self, screen, x, y):
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen.blit(self.image, [x, y])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ship = Ship('Lod.png')
    while True:
        window = pygame.display.set_mode([1000, 1000])
        window.fill([0, 105, 148])

        Key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if Key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            x -= 1
        if Key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            x += 1

        ship.Play(window, x, y)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Does [pump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938170/pygame-key-get-pressed-is-not-working#17940879) help?

Comment: Doubtful. There's a call to `event.get`

Comment: You're resizing the window every frame. That could be an issue so move `pygame.display.set_mode` before the loop. I believe that the images on the window is reset/cleared every time you resize it, but that's just speculations which I haven't tried out yet.

Comment: Yes, the `pygame.display.set_mode` call in the while loop is the problem. It works correctly if you move it out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving `pygame.display.set_mode` out of loop helped. Thanks!