# Not detecting key press in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently working on a game where I wish to give the player an option of four characters to play. Here is my current code to do this:

```
running = 1
charactersChoice = ['char.png', 'char2.png', 'char3.png', 'char4.png']
choice = ''

while choice == '':
    screen.fill((47, 79, 79))
    screen.blit(pygame.image.load(charactersChoice[0]), (100,100))
    screen.blit(pygame.image.load(charactersChoice[1]), (700,100))
    screen.blit(pygame.image.load(charactersChoice[2]), (100,600))
    screen.blit(pygame.image.load(charactersChoice[3]), (700,600))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    #Choose character

    if keys[pygame.K_1]:
        choice = charactersChoice[0]

    if keys[pygame.K_2]:
        choice = charactersChoice[1]

    if keys[pygame.K_3]:
        choice = charactersChoice[2]

    if keys[pygame.K_4]:
        choice = charactersChoice[3]


    pygame.display.flip()


while running == 1:
#rest of code for game here
```

As you can see, I blit the four different character profiles onto the screen and then check if the player has pressed the keys 1-4 to select their option. After selecting their option, it should move onto the main loop. Currently, if I press the key '1' while the code is running, it will not change the variable choice to what is intended.

Hope I have explained my problem well enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pygame.key.get\_pressed() is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938170/pygame-key-get-pressed-is-not-working)

Comment: Try printing out the evaluation of the if statements. See if they are returning true like they should. Also, try printing out `keys`.

Comment: @ShadowMitia I have used pygame.key.get_pressed() again later on in the program but changing this has no impact on the issue.

Comment: Have you tried calling `pygame.event.pump()` before calling `get_pressed()`?

Comment: @MichealO'Dwyer printing out the if statements always returns '0'

Comment: @ShadowMitia This solved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call `pygame.event.pump()` at least once before using `pygame.key.get_pressed()` so that pygame can check what keys have been pressed.