# Only certain keys working when detecting keyboard input in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Keyboard event handling in pygame is working fine if I run the code on my PC, but NOT if I run the same code inside a windows virtual environment.  Only some keys work?!?

If I run the same code from python or pycharm inside a windows virtual machine (the only option I have with my students) then only certain keys work!!!

For some reason I can detect and handle arrow keys, space, etc.  but none of the basic keys 'w' 'a' 's' 'd' work.  They program just sits there and acts like I am not pressing the key.

As I have said, the code works fine if I run it on my pc at home.

Clearly this is an issue with the virtual environment.  Does anyone have any idea if this is a known problem?  Is it something to do with an incorrect installation of python or pygame?   I am stuck!

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_w:
        print('Forward')
    elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
        print('Backward')…
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        print('SPACE')…
```

works fine on my PC, but not inside the virtual environment.

I would expect the code to work in the same way on both?

Comment: **Hello, fellow Reed.** How are you processing the event queue at the end of your loop? I'm not sure about vm settings, but this *might* be relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/q/17938170/7431860

Answer (score 0):

you would better do that this way:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() # this returnes a dictionary of keys

if keys[pygame.K_w]: # if "w" was pressed
    [...]
```

hope this will work